# Cannot show out sql results in PHP

Tags: php

may I ask for help? I have tried to run the sql in SQL Command, it run successfully, but it cannot show out the results when I run the php file, is there any problem in the code? Thank you.

```
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASS', '');
    define('DB_NAME', 'steakhouse');

    $con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

   $sql1 ="SELECT r.MemberId,m.MFirstName,m.MLastName,m.MEmail,r.SeatAmount
             FROM member m,reservation r
             where m.MemberId=r.MemberId AND r.SeatAmount>=10'";


if ($result1 = $con->query($sql1))
{  
    while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_object())
    {
        printf('<tr><td align="center">%s</td>
            <td align="center">%s %s</td>
            <td align="center">%s</td>
            <td align="center">%d</td> </tr> ',

                $row1->MemberId,
                $row1->MFirstName,
                $row1->MLastName,
                $row1->MEmail,
                $row1->SeatAmount);

    }


}
```

Comment: Are you *sure* you've run the same SQL statement successfully?  It appears to have an extra single-quote.

Comment: Print out some debugging information if it is not successful and you will quickly find out what's wrong.

Comment: 99.99% of all questions on SO could probably be avoided if people would learn to show themselves error messages while testing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that single quote at the end of SQL query is not causing exception?

```
$sql1 ="SELECT r.MemberId,m.MFirstName,m.MLastName,m.MEmail,r.SeatAmount
         FROM member m,reservation r
         where m.MemberId=r.MemberId AND r.SeatAmount>=10'";
                                                         ^
```